# Bootstrap scrollspy: <a href="page.html"> won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

Update 1: JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/xz4xsc2r/1/

I created a website using bootstrap and scroll-spy in order to move around the page and make the navbar change depending on which section you are reading. The website has 2 pages. The first one is where the scroll-spy is used. The second one contains some other important information.

My navbar has 4 links, 3 are links to anchors in the samepage, while 1 is a link to the other page. 
Code:

```
        <div id="scroll-spy-target" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#first">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ss-produtos">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ss-equipe">Equipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#ss-contato">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Curvas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Problem: when I click on `Curvas`, nothing happens. I am not redirected to the `page2.html`.

Question: If I remove the `id="scroll-spy-target"` then everything works, but I loose the functionality of scrollspy. How do I keep scroll-spy and make that link work?

Thanks a lot for helping!!!

Comment: can you please upload it on a jsFiddle, or code snippet? just to make more easy to understand

Comment: @Ethaan sorry it took me so long, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/xz4xsc2r/1/    while creating it I observed that the problem started after I added the javascript code to smooth the scrolling, please check it out and tell me what you think! thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because I was using a function to smooth the scrolling when an anchor was clicked. The javascript function was:

```
    $("#scroll-spy-target a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageRef = $(this).attr("href");
        var pageRefPosition = $(pageRef).offset().top ;

        $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop:pageRefPosition
        },400);
    });
```

Which took the `href` attribute from the clicked anchor `<a>`, calculated its offset and scrolled the page (in 400 milliseconds).
The problem then occurred because my link was store inside an `<a>` tag, so instead of loading the page, it tried to scroll to the link, so nothing happened.

The solution was to change load the page if it found a link inside the `<a>` tag:

```
    $("#scroll-spy-target a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pageRef = $(this).attr("href");

        if(pageRef[0] != '#') {
            window.location.href = pageRef;
        } else {
            var pageRefPosition = $(pageRef).offset().top ;

            $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop:pageRefPosition
            },400);
        }
    });
```

Because anchors always start with `#`, anything else must be a link (hypothesis).

Answer (score 0):

From the [boostrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-examples). add the data-spy and data-target to your body tag 
where the data-target is the class of your navbar. For example:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. The scrollspy is working perfectly, that's not the issue. The problem is how to add a link to an external webpage in the same navbar.